# How to toggle off Caps Lock by Shift key?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I get used to turn <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> off by <kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows. That way I never need to check whether <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is on when I just want to type a first letter in uppercase. But how can I do the same in Ubuntu?

iF <kbd>sHIFT</kbd> CANCELS <kbd>cAPS lOCK</kbd> YOU RARELY NEED TO FIX YOUR TEXT TYPED IN WRONG CASE.

Comment: Even though your question applies to Ubuntu 14.04 and answer was about 20.04 as you last were seen 14 minutes ago, kindly accept it. BTW 55 points in 5 years is close to a record.

Comment: I agree to accept an answer. But first I want to make sure it works! The problem is I don't have that system installed any more, so I am now installing gnome on my father's computer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First install gnome-tweak-tool by using this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Now open 'Tweaks' application, then go to : Keyboard & Mouse → Keyboard → Additional Layout Options → Miscellaneous compatibility options → check '**Shift cancels Caps Lock**'. Close window.

Works fine in **Ubuntu 20.04.**

[image: 'Additional Layout Options' screenshot]

---

Update for **Ubuntu 22.04:**

First install gnome-tweaks by using this command (thanks @Paul P)

```
$ apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

Then open "Tweaks", find option within Keyboard & Mouse → Keyboard → Additional Layout Options → Compatibility options → and check '**Both Shift together enable Caps Lock; one Shift key disables it.**'.

Comment: This is the exact solution OP was looking for!

Comment: This is in the advanced keyboard options. I don't think one need to install anything additional to get these options.

Comment: On newer Ubuntu version (e.g. 22.04) you may have to use `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`.

Comment: User @walter-monroe suggested change with argument `"Shift cancels Caps Lock" in Gnome Tweaks only works when Shift is pressed and released. The intended solution is for Shift to be pressed in combination with another key when starting a new sentence.` which I agree, but his proposed option `"Both Shift together enable Caps Lock; one Shift key disables it."` do not meet that behaviour (I tested within Ubuntu 20.04.5). It think there not exist such an option currently.

Answer (score 2):

I have also been searching for the same functionality. It's easy to use, you never have to delete those uppercase characters when you don't need them. Just by pressing Shift to start the sentence with an uppercase character, you "automatically" deactivate CapsLock.

Here are the instructions for Linux Mint:

Go to System Settings > Keyboard.

Next, choose your keyboard layout, then click Options...

Under "Miscellaneous compatibility options", check the box next to "Both Shift keys together activate Caps Lock, one Shift key deactivates".

I have no Ubuntu available to test, but hopefully the instructions are equally valid.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the same settings for Ubuntu :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way, just try it. Open any text editor (gedit, Libre Office Writer,etc) and write with Shift pressed.

As for Shift turning off Caps Lock, I don't know if there's such an option, but
if you want to get notified every time Caps Lock changes try installing indicator-keylock.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock indicator-keylock-icons

Comment: I mean I want to switch **Caps Lock** off by just pressing and releasing **Shift**. There is such an option in Windows XP. In common I need to press **Caps Lock** once again to switch it off when it is on, that's why I must always know its state or start typing. It is inconvenient when you get used to switch it off always by just pressing **Shift**.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest keybinding for my fingers to enable Caps Lock is to remap it to double Shift. You can achieve that using the `gnome-tweaks` tool mentioned in the first answer: *Keyboard & Mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options* -> *Miscellaneous compatibility options* -> check *Both Shift together enable Caps Lock*.

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1283230)