# How to disable Caps Lock through Shift key?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

My question is similar to [How to toggle off Caps Lock by Shift key?](https://askubuntu.com/q/562020/181442), but I am running version 14.04 and **X**ubuntu (XFCE). Also the only answer there doesn't actually answer the question and I haven't found this piece of information elsewhere on the web.

What I'd like is:

- <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> should enable the keyboard's CAPS mode.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> should disable the mode.

I prefer to configure these once-per-installation options through some GUI that's part of the base installation, but a complete console command(s) would be appreciated as well.

#### EDIT 1: Clarify why this is NOT a duplicate of the ["How to toggle off Caps Lock by Shift key?"](https://askubuntu.com/q/562020/181442) question

As I tried to sum up above already, there are the following reasons why the linked question doesn't help me:

1. The linked question is for *U*buntu, but I am asking for *X*ubuntu. That means my desktop environment is XFCE, not Unity.
2. The version of my system is 14.04, not 14.10 as in the linked question. That might or might not make a difference.
3. The only "answer" to the linked question doesn't really answer the posed question, that's why I didn't even try it out: there is simply no point installing a piece of software *just to indicate the Caps Lock status* when I am after some configuration *to change the behaviour of my keyboard*. In fact, I believe that this answer should be deleted and I think the OP of that question [would agree with me on that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562020/how-to-toggle-off-caps-lock-by-shift-key#comment773190_562059).

Please let me know if these points need even further clarification.

Comment: check: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149971/how-do-you-remap-a-key-to-the-caps-lock-key-in-xubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to toggle off Caps Lock by Shift key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562020/how-to-toggle-off-caps-lock-by-shift-key)

Comment: @Info-Screen: Added explanation why this is a) not a duplicate and b) why the only answer (if you could even call it that) doesn't solve my (or the that question's OP's) problem.

Comment: @Olimjon: I am not trying to remap anything. I simply want to have the Shift key (in addition to its normal function) *also* disable the Caps Lock if it was set before.

Answer (score 1):

Neat idea.

This is probably what you want:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_Lock"
```

I don't use Xfce, but you should be able to do something with *Settings > Session > Application Autostart*.